# How do I replace the "var" keywords in this code with "let" and "const"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I replace the "var" keywords with either "let" or "const", I get a userChoice is not defined error.

I have already tried replacing everything with either "let" or "const". I have also put userChoice into a function and invoked the function whenever I needed it. I have also tried putting the entire while loop into a function. The programs works perfectly with "var".

The furthest I got with "let" and "const" is this / As soon as I tried putting it into a while loop it stopped working:

```
const arrayList = [];
let userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
// Array list is empty array
if (userChoice === "new") {
    let newTodo = prompt('Enter a new todo');
    arrayList.push(newTodo);
} else if (userChoice === "list") {
    console.log(arrayList);
}
```

Working code:

```
var arrayList = [];
var userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
// Array list is empty array
while (userChoice !== "quit") {
    if (userChoice === "new") {
        var newTodo = prompt('Enter a new todo');
        arrayList.push(newTodo);
    } else if (userChoice === "list") {
        console.log(arrayList);
    }
    var userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
}
```

I expect this program to continually prompt unless you say "quit". You type "new" to add a new todo, and "list" to list all todos.

Comment: Please show us the replacements you tried.

Comment: In the second to last line, you are re-declaring userChoice. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that that code declares `userChoice` twice, the second `var` on it is unnecessary:

```
var arrayList = [];
var userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
// Array list is empty array
while (userChoice !== "quit") {
    if (userChoice === "new") {
        var newTodo = prompt('Enter a new todo');
        arrayList.push(newTodo);
    } else if (userChoice === "list") {
        console.log(arrayList);
    }
    var userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
//  ^^^---------------------------------------------------- here
}
```

With `var` it didn't matter because `var` has function scope (or global scope, if used outside a function) and multiple declarations are ignored, but it matters with `let` because `let` is *block-scoped*, so declaring a new `userChoice` within the block shadows the outer one. (Multiple declarations with `let` are an error in the same scope, since it doesn't make sense to do that, and allowing it would have complicated things.)

Just remove that second `var` and replace the other `var`s with `let` (or you could use `const` for `arrayList` and `newTodo`, unless code not shown assigns a new array to `arrayList` later):

```
const arrayList = []; // Or let
let userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
// Array list is empty array
while (userChoice !== "quit") {
    if (userChoice === "new") {
        const newTodo = prompt('Enter a new todo'); // Or let if you prefer
        arrayList.push(newTodo);
    } else if (userChoice === "list") {
        console.log(arrayList);
    }
    userChoice = prompt('What would you like to do?');
}
```